# Разграничение доступа в контейнер docker

Tags: linux, docker, iptables

Привет всем! Созрел у меня такой вопрос: А как ограничивать доступ к контейнерам по сети?

Ну вот есть у вас linux на котором docker , так же на этом linux'е у вас есть iptables который полностью закрыт от всего мира и открыт только для вас, так как вы параноик. В один прекрасный день вы ставите nginx `docker run -it -p 80:80 nginx` и вуаля, 80 порт становится открыт всему миру, так как проброс портов выполняется из таблицы *nat* в iptables что находится ниже чем *filter* в котором у вас все правила находятся. Что делать в таком случае? Перетаскивать из filter всё что у вас есть в nat? А как тогда быть с динамичностью заполнения таблицы докером? Да и вообще это неудобно совершенно. Или может я чего не понимаю...